# Asbestos between floors

Tags: flooring, asbestos

I have a layer of white paper or cardboard like material houses between the subfloor and a layer of wood on top. The stuff crumbles pretty easy. I do not intend to demo the floor or anything so my question is, will this potential asbestos be okay living there between wood floors or as I walk do I grind it up and move it about to the point where it will leak through cracks etc.  thanks.

Comment: How old is the house, and how long do you guess the floor has been down that has the questionable material under it?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the asbestos material is contained between your subfloors you are fine.  It doesn't matter if it crumples up being sandwiched in there.  You may have to take extra precautions taking it out in this case but it isn't a concern in current state.